# Vim: delete from the cursor until the end of the bracket (or a character)

Tags: vim

I would like delete everything from the cursor until the end of the bracket

For example: (the cursor is after "is") 
[this is *my text*] -> [this is]

How can I do?

I would something like *di]*..., but don't delete the text before the cursor

Comment: have a look at `f` and `t`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To delete text from the cursor until a certain character <kbd>]</kbd> in normal mode, use <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> or <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>. The difference between <kbd>t</kbd> and <kbd>f</kbd> is that <kbd>f</kbd> will also delete <kbd>]</kbd>.

Assuming your curser is after *is* in `[this is my text]`, typing

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>

in normal mode will give you `[this is]` as result.
If you want to delete the bracket `]` too, type

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>

instead to get `[this is`.